# How do I prevent a keyup event from interrupting a keydown event in jQuery?

Tags: keyboard, jquery-animate, jquery, keyboard-events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cross-browser way to get automatically repeating keydown events when key is held down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14027818/cross-browser-way-to-get-automatically-repeating-keydown-events-when-key-is-held)

I'm trying to create a simple game in JavaScript/CSS/HTML, and I am using jQuery (and a little bit of Underscore) to handle key presses. The player controls a block using arrow keys. I've run into a problem with handling multiple keypresses at the same time. I have a system in place where a closure keeps track of all arrow keys that are pressed. This works well if the player presses keys in the following sequence:

1. Player presses Down (block moves down)
2. Player presses Left (block moves diagonally down-left)
3. Player releases Down (block moves left)
4. Player releases Left (block stops

However, the block stops if steps 3 and 4 are reversed. Here is what actually happens in that case:

1. Player presses Down (block moves down)
2. Player presses Left (block moves diagonally down-left)
3. Player releases Left (block stops)

The expected behavior is that on step 3, the block would continue to move down, rather than stopping completely.

From traces I have put in the code, it appears that a keyup event actually stops the propagation of further keydown events, even when my finger is still holding down one of the arrow keys.

Here is a snippet of relevant code. Can anyone tell me where the problem might be?

```js
// Creates an animation handler for a specific element.
// Animation reacts to any changes as they are submitted
var getMovementAnimator = function(element) {
    var params = {},
        $element = $(element);
    return function(changes) {
        _.each(changes, function(val, key) {
            // Remove null or zeroish keys from animation params
            if ( (val == 0 || !val) && _.has(params, key)) {
                delete params[key];
            } else {
                params[key] = '+=' + val + 'px';
            }
        });
        $element.animate(params, {duration: 0, queue: false});
        console.log(params);
    };
};

// Determines direction and speed of movement for an element
// after a keypress event
var getMovementChange = function(keyEvent, keydown) {
    var isMoving = !!keydown,
        params   = {},
        dir      = '',
        speed    = keydown ? 5 : 0,
        arrows   = {left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40};
    switch (keyEvent.which) {
        case arrows.left:
            dir = 'left';
            speed = -speed;
            break;
        case arrows.up:
            dir = 'top';
            speed = -speed;
            break;
        case arrows.right:
            dir = 'left';
            break;
        case arrows.down:
            dir = 'top';
            break;
    }
    // If key hit not one of above, do nothing
    if (!dir) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!speed) {
        console.log('key up: ', dir);
    }
    params[dir] = speed;
    return params;
}

// Sets up key handlers
$(document).ready(function() {
    var board = $('#board'),
        animatePlayer = getMovementAnimator('.player');
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var changes = getMovementChange(e, true);
        animatePlayer(changes);
    }).keyup(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var changes = getMovementChange(e, false);
        animatePlayer(changes);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Further search on Stack Overflow (using the right keywords) showed me that the issue I am seeing is not actually a bug in my code. Rather, [this is expected behavior for the operating system](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5841905/959934).

However, I found [a workaround which I believe will resolve the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14027886/959934).