# keydown event not fired, why?

Tags: javascript, events

In JavaScript, I hold two keys down, and `keydown` is fired perfectly. When I release one of the keys, `keyup`is fired. So far so good. But I am still holding one key down, so why arent `keydown` fired? I need this to happen in my game. Am I doing something wrong? Is this the expected response? Is there a work around or something?

```
window.addEventListener("keydown",
function (e) {
    console.log('down');
}, false);

window.addEventListener('keyup',
function (e) {
    console.log('up');
}, false);
```

Comment: not sure I'm following, but why would keydown fire again for a key that already fired it and you haven't released it yet?

Comment: Keydown fires repeatedly while the key is down, but seems that if he hits another key and then makes keyup, the first one stops firing keydown. Keypress just fires once

Comment: Keydown fires repeatedly...? Huh. That's actually news to me.

Comment: seems to be working fine for me [http://jsfiddle.net/ffotkhvt/](jsfiddle)

Comment: @radbyx that is OS standard behaviour, not a bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841853/keydown-repetition-breaks-when-keyup-event-for-another-key-is-fired/5841905#5841905 . Depends on what are you trying to make, you could do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14027818/cross-browser-way-to-get-automatically-repeating-keydown-events-when-key-is-held/14027886#14027886

Comment: I making a game, supose you have man running the right way. and then i press up for a jump, i still hold down right, beacuse i want him to keep running right. but when i release the 'up', the 'keydown' event for the right-key im still holding down, isn't being fired. So the man stops..

Comment: I seems like this fiddle got the solution, thanks @juvian! http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/aD3Eg/

Comment: No problem, good luck with your game!

Comment: Thanks, I want to learn JavaScript, so i'm trying to make the game Bomb Jack. It has some controls mechanics for multiple keypresses, that I needed to apply. I can do this now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you're trying to do something like this:

```js
var down = false;
var up = false;
document.body.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    if(e.which === 40) {
        down = true;
    }
    
    if(e.which === 38) {
        up = true;
    }
});

document.body.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
    if(e.which === 40) {
        down = false;
    }
    
    if(e.which === 38) {
        up = false;
    }
    
    // logic here for one but not the other
    if(down && !up) {
        alert('down but not up!');
    }
});
```