# keydown/up counters not behaving as they should when changing keys then holding the next

Tags: jquery, keyboard-events, keydown

https://jsfiddle.net/jxbg24au/

```
$(document).keydown(function(event)
{
     var kc= event.keyCode;
   if (!event.originalEvent.repeat) {
       pressedCount++;
       setCheck();
   } 
});
$(document).keyup(function()
{
   pressedCount--
   setCheck();
});
```

this code is the relevant stuff that doesnt work in a specific case

if someone presses a key, then immediantly switches to another, then holds the second key, pressedCount is incremented another time that it shouldnt be, it also increments in other specific cases when using multiple keys and switching between them, although this bug is the most basic case, so it might aswell be the root of the problem

currently what i think might be happening is the check for `event.originalEvent/repeat` works everytime apart from the first time the key repeating thing happens, which would make sense seeing as technically the repeat event wouldnt be activated until the keys begin to repeat

any help would be appreciated

Comment: This is because the repetition is stopped when another key is pressed/released. Watch the log in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/jxmvrwnp/) and you'll see it happening. Steps: hold down any key, hold down another key, release the first key, release the second key. You'll see in the log that the repetition of the second key being held was stopped when the first key was released, then started again. This is why the value gets incremented one more time than you expect. There's nothing you can do about this.

Comment: For more information on the above, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5841905/519413). If you can edit your answer to describe your goal better we may be able to offer alternatives

Comment: currently im using this for a movement system, so if there is a way to detect if no keys are currently being pressed that would be helpful in my circumstance

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by an issue with Chromium based browsers. See [Pressing 2 keys, release 1, produces keydown of other key again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50372849)

Firefox runs your example correctly. Edge (as of this date not yet Chromium based) fails anyway because it regards all keydown's repeat properties as `false`. I don't know how Safari handles the example.

This can be seen using [Keyboard Event Tester](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/d4e/raw-file/tip/key-event-test.html) and [Keyboard Event Viewer](http://w3c.github.io/uievents/tools/key-event-viewer.html) which display repeat values and other information as keys are pressed, held and released.

With Chromium in particular, after a keyup occurs while another repeating key is held, the held key's next keydown event will report its `.repeat` property once as `false`, and resumes to `true` for subsequent repeating events, thus causing an extra increment in the counter. Firefox maintains `true` throughout.

A workaround is to set a flag, `lastHeldKey`, that remembers the current/latest pressed key's `.code`, checking for a match at keydown in order to skip counter increment as if the `.repeat` were `true`, and checking for a match at keyup to reset/clear the flag in case the next keydown happens to be the same as the released key. If not a match at keyup then allow flag to remain with its latest keydown `.code` value.

```
let pressedCount = 0,
  lastHeldKey = '';
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
  if (!event.originalEvent.repeat && event.originalEvent.code != lastHeldKey) {
    lastHeldKey = event.originalEvent.code;
    pressedCount++;
    setCheck();
  }
});
$(document).keyup(function(event) {
  if (event.originalEvent.code == lastHeldKey) {
    lastHeldKey = '';
  }
  pressedCount--;
  setCheck();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d83nvfLr/